# Swift 2.0 String try keyword

Tags: ios, swift2

In Swift 1.2 my code was

```
let examplePhoneNumber =  phoneNumberUtil.getExampleNumberForType(countryCode, type: NBEPhoneNumberTypeMOBILE);
```

But the migration tool in XCode 7 Beta changed it to

```
let examplePhoneNumber = try? phoneNumberUtil.getExampleNumberForType(countryCode, type: NBEPhoneNumberTypeMOBILE);
```

But there is a compile error asking me to add a `;` after `try?`

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: I think that the fact that your code isn't able to identify the `do-catch` structure you have there means that your compiler somehow still thinks that your code is still Swift 1.2. Your `try?` syntax is correct. Assuming your project is setup properly, it may possibly be a bug.

Comment: I still have Xcode 6 installed. Might that be the cause? @ZacharyEspiritu

Comment: @JayVDiyk It shouldn't, I'm using both Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 on my machine without problems. In your case: check that you are running Xcode 7 **beta 6**.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7 beta 6 added a new `try?` keyword, which attempts to call a method that may throw an error and wraps the result in an optional if it succeeds, otherwise returns `nil` if it throws. It allows one to handle calling methods that throw an error if you only care if it succeeded or failed and don't care what the actual error was.

If you're using `try?` and not `try`, then it doesn't need to be in a `do` block with a `catch` block. Although that doesn't appear to be why it's complaining.

The error it's giving is what Xcode 6 would give if you opened your code that was already migrated to Xcode 7 in Xcode 6. So check which version of Xcode you have it opened in. If you have it open in Xcode 7, try performing a clean and then rebuild it to see if the error goes away. If you have it open in Xcode 6, then that's your problem right there. Once you migrate to Swift 2 syntax, you can't open it again in older versions of Xcode or you'll get compile errors.